# if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2n-1}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I think this statement is wrong.
Consider $a_1=1, a_2=-1, a_3=1/2, a_4=-1/2, a_5=1/3, a_6=-1/3, \dots$
Is my logic correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: Yes, it's a wrong statement. but if we put some additional conditions, like (monotonically) increasing/decreasing, maybe the statement can be true...

Comment: If all the terms are nonnegative, then of course the result is correct.

Comment: Can you give a proof for if all terms are nonnegative, the statement is true?

Answer (score 2):

Proof of the problem with the additional condition:

> All terms are nonnegative.

If all terms are nonnegative, $S_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{2k} \geq 0$ and $T_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{2k-1} \geq 0$.

Since $R_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{2k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{2k}, \ 0 \leq T_n \leq R_n.$

Thus, $T_n$ has the lower/upper bound.

Since the sequence $T_n$ is monotonously increasing and $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} R_n = \alpha$,

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{2k-1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} T_n$ converges by Monotone Convergence Theorem.

+) There is another additional condition that makes the statement correct:

> $a_n$ is monotonously increasing/decreasing.

If $a_n$ is monotonously increasing, $a_{2k-2}\leq a_{2k-1}\leq a_{2k}$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle a_1+ \sum_{k=2}^{n} a_{2k-2} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{2k-1} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{2k}$.

Adding $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{2k-1}$, we get:

$\displaystyle a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} a_k \leq 2\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{2k-1} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{2n} a_k.$

Let the three sequences above $R_n, S_n, T_n. (R_n \leq S_n \leq T_n)$

Then, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} R_n = a_1+\alpha, \lim_{n \to \infty} T_n = \alpha$. ($\alpha = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n.$)

If $\exists t \text{ s.t. } a_t>0, \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n > a_t > 0, \text{ Diverges.}$

Therefore, $a_n \leq 0 \text{ for } \forall n$, $S_n$: monotonely decreasing.

$\therefore S_n $ converges bt Monotone Convergence Theorem.

$\\$

I recommend you to try the monotonously decreasing case, which is quite same to those above.

(Or, you can make $b_n=-a_n$ and show $b_n$'s convergence.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Notice that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N a_n = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{$N$ is even} \\
1/k, & \text{$N$ is odd and $N=2k-1$} \end{cases}
$$
and so the partial sums converge to $0$ as $N\to\infty$.

Meanwhile,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n
$$
which trivially diverges.

Comment: Did you mean to define $a_n$ with the piecewise and not the sum?

Comment: No. The partial sums should follow that piecewise definition.